# When to use ADOX instead of ADCX?

Tags: assembly, x86, adx

The only difference mentioned in the [Intel instruction set reference](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/a4/60/325383-sdm-vol-2abcd.pdf) is the usage of the overflow-flag instead of the carry-flag. When does one use `ADOX` instead of `ADCX` to perform an unsigned addition with a carry?

Comment: Normally you should use `adc` because it's smaller (fewer instruction bytes), and writes all flags (avoiding any partial-flag merging penalties for later instructions on all CPUs).  Only use either `adcx` or `adox` if you specifically want their behaviour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ADOX can be used when you don't want to overwrite the carry flag, like you've stored something like a rotation out.

However their main usage is to accelerate big-int arithmetics because now you can do two additions with carry in parallel in conjunction with `mulx`

From Intel's paper [New Instructions Support Large Integer Arithmetic](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-large-integer-arithmetic-paper.pdf)

> ## ADCX/ADOX Instructions
>
> The `adcx` and `adox` instructions are extensions of the `adc` instruction, designed to support two separate carry chains. They are defined as:
>
> ```
> adcx dest/src1, src2
> adox dest/src1, src2
> ```
>
> Both instructions compute the sum of `src1` and `src2` plus a carry-in and generate an output sum dest and a carry-out. The difference between these two instructions is that `adcx` uses the CF flag for the carry in and carry out (leaving the OF flag unchanged), whereas the `adox` instruction uses the OF flag for the carry in and carry out (leaving the CF flag unchanged).

Related:

[What is the difference between the ADC and ADCX instructions on ia32/ia64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29747508/995714)